# Migrate VB 6.0 ActiveX control to MFC ActiveX Controls

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, activex

I have created ActiveX Controls in VB 6.0. I am planning to migrate VB 6.0 controls to MFC Controls. I don't have much idea how to do this. I searched in internet there is no step by steps to do this. Is there any way to convert the implementation from VB 6.0 to MFC? 
or any steps to create new ActiveX Controls in MFC using Visual studio 2008?

Answer (score 3):

You're asking this question 14 years too late, time has not been kind to ActiveX controls.  So sure, you'll have trouble googling for help.  Nevertheless, it is still very well documented in the MSDN library, a step-by-step tutorial [starts here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k194shk8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  Do keep in mind that there's no "migration" from VB6, it requires a complete rewrite.

Comment: Thank you for your reference and explanation. I will try to create from scratch by following the step-by-strp tutorial.

Comment: VS 2017 still has an ATL ActiveX control wizard. A big advantage of ATL over VB6 is 64-bit support.